# Why aren't assertions such as $ and ^ part of a regular grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar, state-machine, automata

I read that `$` and `^` are not elements of a (formal) regular expression. Why is this so? First of all, wouldn't the `^` start-of-string essentially be the initial state of the state diagram? So, for example, why couldn't a FSM look like this to capture `^a$`?

```
       a              
-> q1 ---> q2
```

And, if this isn't allowed, is it because there is something that would inherently disobey how Regular Expression are defined? Or is merely that assertions were introduced after Regular Expressions were first defined, and so aren't included?

Comment: The regular expression or regular grammar of formal language theory describes an entire sentence (just as formal grammars do). Evidently, if L is a regular language over alphabet Σ, then Σ\*LΣ* is the (also regular) language which describes any sentence which includes an element of L as a substring. That rather uninteresting fact is rarely used in formal language theory, unlike practical programming, where using regular expressions for prefix or substring matches is often useful.

Comment: @rici -- I think I follow (fingers crossed). Does that mean then that the practical construct just isn't needed/necessary in formal language theory (but still possible)? Or that -- similar to something like backreferences -- it cannot be captured in a regular language?

Comment: It can be captured. I did so in my comment:-)

Comment: The concept which is not usually considered on formal language theory is "captures", which is a parsing problem rather than a recognition problem. Curiously, parsing (figuring out the syntactic structure of an input) is rarely treated in parsing theory, which tends to focus on recognition. If you have a CFG, that's not a big deal, but there's no canonical transformation from regular expression to CFG. It turns out that regular expressions are not very interesting as parsers, even though programmers try to do that far too often.